# Passar valor do javaScript para php

Tags: php, javascript

Não consigo passar o valor do php para o javaScript realmente é dessa forma ?

```js
var session = "<?php session_start(); $_SESSION['NOME'];?>"

alert(session);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<?php
  
  session_start(); 
  
  $_SESSION['NOME'] = "João";
  
  echo $_SESSION['NOME'];
  
?>
```

Comment: Isso só funciona se vc estiver num arquivo php e printando dentro de uma tag `<script>`. Exemplo:
`<script> var session = '<?php echo $_SESSION['NOME'];?>';</script>`

Comment: Java Script é uma linguagem Client Side e PHP Server Side. O código que você colocou está sendo executado do lado do cliente, no qual não interpreta código PHP.

Comment: E por padráo `sesstion_start();` do PHP deve estar no começo do arquivo antes de qualquer saída de código.

Comment: Você pode usar JavaScript dentro do PHP, mas não PHP dentro do JavaScript. Não vai funcionar. Um será interpretado do lado do servidor, o outro no navegador.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vamos lá, primeiramente, o **PHP** é uma linguagem **Server-Side**, ou seja, ela é executada no servidor, já o **javaScript** é **Client-side**, ou seje, é executada no computador do cliente, tudo ocorre na seguinte ordem:

- O **Servidor** pega o arquivo e interpreta, traduzindo tudo para **HTML, CSS e JavaScript**
- O **Browser** do usuário exibe o resultado dos 3 anteriores combinados.

Um exemplo, você possui o seguinte código:

```
<?php
    $strikes = 0;
?>
...
<script>
    function increase() {
        <?php $strikes++; ?>
    }
</script>
```

O que acontece é que primeiro o Servidor interpreta o código, logo, ao ver a linha

```
<?php $strikes++; ?>
```

Ele vai executá-la antes de mandar o resultado final ao cliente, o que resultará em:

```
<?php
    $strikes = 1;
?>
...
<script>
    function increase() {

    }
</script>
```

O que você deve fazer é criar a sessão em outra página, a qual seja direto php, **supondo** que esta sessão seje de um login, por exemplo, você pode mandar as informações do JavaScript para o PHP de outra página usando o **AJAX**:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'login.php',
  data: $("form").serialize(),
  success: function(response) { ... },
});
```